# AngularJS Material Chips always editable if md-enable-chip-edit is used

Tags: angularjs

Has anyone got a workaround for this issue that I just filed?

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10657

Basically in the AngularJS material chips, md-enable-chip-edit can be set to "true" or "false" but cannot point to a scope variable, in which case it is always editable.

Answer (score 0):

From the `md-enable-chip-edit` documentation:

> Set this to "true" to enable editing of chip contents. The user can go
>   into edit mode by pressing the space or enter keys, or by double
>   clicking on the chip. Chip editing is only supported for chips using
>   the basic template. **Note: This attribute is only evaluated once; it
>   is not watched.**

[mdChips API Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips)